# HasOne not being patched properly

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

How would a form be built to save many hasOne relationships? Issue is that input data isn't being patched properly as it always shows the existing data for `escalations` and not that which was input in the form.

In the example below, it should be a different comment and date.

[image]

Relationships:

- `requests` hasMany `service_line_entries`
- `service_line_entries` hasOne `escalation_entries`

Structure:

```
table: requests
id
...

table: service_line_entries
id
request_id
value

table: escalation_entries
id
service_line_entry_id
value
```

Existing form:

```
<?= $this->Form->create($request) ?>
//for each service_line_entries
<?= $this->Form->hidden('service_line_entries.0.escalation_entry.id', ['value' => $escalation->id]); ?>
<?= $this->Form->hidden('service_line_entries.0.escalation_entry.service_line_entry_id', ['value' => $escalation->service_line_entry_id]); ?>
<?= $this->Form->control('service_line_entries.0.escalation_entry.value'); ?>
```

Existing edit function:

```
public function edit ($id = null)
{
    $request = $this->Requests->get($id, ['contain' => ['ServiceLineEntries','ServiceLineEntries.EscalationEntries']]);

    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put']))
    {

        $request = $this->Requests->patchEntity($request, $this->request->getData(), ['associated' => ['ServiceLineEntries', 'ServiceLineEntries.EscalationEntries']]);
        //doesn't feature new data, only existing data
        debug($request);
    }
}
```

Entity 'service_line_entries`:

```
protected $_accessible = [
        ...
        'escalation_entries' => true
    ];
```

**Update #1**

I had to switch the following:

```
<?= $this->Form->hidden('service_line_entries.0.escalation_entry.service_line_entry_id', ['value' => $escalation->service_line_entry_id]); ?>
```

For this

```
<?= $this->Form->hidden('service_line_entries.0.id', ['value' => $escalation->service_line_entry_id]); ?>
```

Comment: Look at how the data is structured when you read it. There usually are no numeric indices for a `hasOne` association, as that's a 1:1 association, meaning there's only 1 associated entry, so it should be just `service_line_entries.escalation_entry`. **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data**

Comment: It should be `escalation_entry` in `$_accessible` instead of `escalation_entries`?

Comment: @ndm I have many service_line_entries on the same screen. No need to index them?

Comment: @Greg Schmidt, I changed my file per your suggestion, cleared my cache and the changes don't appear in the patched variable.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed things up, actually with many service line entries you need the index. Greg's observation is correct though, the accessible entry needs to use the actual singular property name. `service_line_entries` also needs to be accessible in the `Request` entity.

Comment: @ndm I was missing the accessible in Requests entity! I also had to make a slight adjustment to one of the hidden fields, see Update #1. Thanks!